# Show / Hide elements inside a Component using a Service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-observable

I created a Tabs component and I am using it as follows ([StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-communication)):

```
<tabs>

  <tab title="Tab 1">
    <div toolbar>
      <message><span>Message 1: </span></message>
      <span>Note 1</span>
    </div>
    <content1>
      <p>Content 1</p>
    </content1>
  </tab>

  <tab title="Tab 2">
    <div toolbar>
      <message><span>Message 2: </span></message>
      <span>Note 2</span>
    </div>
    <content2>
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </content2>
  </tab>

</tabs>
```

I need to share some `data` inside each `tab` so I created a TabService:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' // >> Not sure if this should be in root ...
})

export class TabService {
  data: any;  
}
```

As an example I defined data inside `content1` as an observable and used it to define data in `TabService`:

```
export class Content1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private tabService: TabService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getData().subscribe(x => {
      this.tabService.data = x;
    });

  }

  public getData() {

    let data$ = new Observable(observer => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next({ showMessage: true });
        observer.complete();
      }, 1000);
     });

     return data$;

  }

}
```

And I am also injecting that TabService inside the TabComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  templateUrl: './tab.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab.component.css'],
  providers: [TabService]
})

export class TabComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() active: boolean;
  @Input() title: string;

  constructor(private tabService: TabService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    // I tried to log the value of tabService.data but it is undefined (??)
    this.tabService.data.subscribe(data => console.log(data));

  }

}
```

**Question**

The question is how to hide in `Tab 1`, where `content1` is, the two spans:

```
    <message><span>Message 2: </span></message>
    <span>Note 2</span>
```

One is a child of `tab1` and another is a child of `message` which is a child of `tab1`?

The spans should be hidden according to the value of `showMessage` in TabService data property.

The same would also apply to Tab 2 ... Both Tab 1 and Tab 2 should behave independently.

Comment: I don't get the question, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hide the 2 `span` tags when `tabService.data.showMessage` is false.

Comment: your datahandling looks very strange... nevertheless `data: any;` should be a `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: ... also you could take a look at the material implementation of tabs: https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/material/tabs

Comment: @Nickolaus Yes, I can use BehaviorSubject. I was just trying to make this work somehow. I am not using Angular Material tabs as I needed something simpler and that could include a feature in layout that Angular Material does not allow.

Comment: @Nickolaus But do you know how to show/hide the tags from the data in tab service?

Answer (score 0):

> The spans should be hidden according to the value of showMessage in
>   TabService data property.

In other words you need that the a `showMessage` will be set according to a subscription inside the `TabService`.

Here is a small example of an injectable service with a `showMessageSubscription`, once the `.next(..)` is being triggered with its current value, every other component can subscribe to it with `.subscribe(..)`.

`tabs.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable()
export class TabService {
    showMessageSubscription = new Subject<Boolean>();
    showMessage: Boolean;

    setShowMessage(showMessage: Boolean) {
        this.showMessage = showMessage;
        this.showMessageSubscription.next(this.showMessage);
    }
}
```

`content1.component.ts`:

```
export class Content1Component implements OnInit {
    showMessage: Boolean;
    private subscription: Subscription;
    constructor(private tabService: TabService) { }

    ngOnInit() {    
          this.subscription = this.tabService.showMessageSubscription
              .subscribe(
                (showMessage: Boolean) => {
                  console.log(showMessage);
                  this.showMessage = showMessage;
                }
          );

          this.fakeSetShowMessage();
    }

    public fakeSetShowMessage() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.tabService.setShowMessage(true);
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.tabService.setShowMessage(false);
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

To avoide Memory leaks you will need to implement a `OnDestroy`:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```